# alternative to subsetting in R

Tags: r, optimization

I have a df, YearHT, 6.5M x 55 columns. There is specific information I want to extract and add but only based on an aggregate values. I am using a for loop to subset the large df, and then performing the computations.

I have heard that for loops should be avoided, and I wonder if there is a way to avoid a for loop that I have used, as when I run this query it takes ~3hrs.

Here is my code:

```
srt=NULL
for(i in doubletCounts$Var1){
    s=subset(YearHT,YearHT$berthlet==i)
    e=unlist(c(strsplit(i,'\\|'),median(s$berthtime)))
    srt=rbind(srt,e)
}
srt=data.frame(srt)
s2=data.frame(srt$X2,srt$X1,srt$X3)
colnames(s2)=colnames(srt)
s=rbind(srt,s2)
```

doubletCounts is 700 x 3 df, and each of the values is found within the large df.

I would be glad to hear any ideas to optimize/speed up this process.

Comment: Could you provide a small sample of your data set so we can test code? You can get the sample by using `dput()` (make sure you only select the first 10 or so lines)

Comment: Since you're working on a very large dataset, why not try `data.table`? It's a lot faster than data frames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a fast solution using `data.table` , although it is not completely clear from your question what is the `output` you want to get.

```
# load library
  library(datat.table)

# convert your dataset into data.table
  setDT(YearHT)

# subset YearHT keeping values that are present in doubletCounts$Var1
  YearHT_df <- YearHT[ berthlet %in% doubletCounts$Var1]

# aggregate values 
  output <-   YearHT_df[ , .( median= median(berthtime)) ]
```

Comment: I definitely must remember to work with data tables, they are much faster. I used them a few times, but always resort to dfs.

Answer (score 0):

`for` loops aren't necessarily something to avoid, but there are certain ways of using `for` loops that should be avoided.  You've committed the classic `for` loop blunder here.

```
srt = NULL
for (i in index)
{
  [stuff]
  srt = rbind(srt, [stuff])
}
```

is bound to be slower than you would like because each time you hit `srt = rbind(...)`, you're asking R to do all sorts of things to figure out what kind of object `srt` needs to be and how much memory to allocate to it.  When you know what the length of your output needs to be up front, it's better to do

```
srt <- vector("list", length = doubletCounts$Var1)
for(i in doubletCounts$Var1){
    s=subset(YearHT,YearHT$berthlet==i)
    srt[[i]] = unlist(c(strsplit(i,'\\|'),median(s$berthtime)))
}
srt=data.frame(srt)
```

Or the `apply` alternative of

```
srt = lapply(doubletCounts$Var1,
       function(i)
       {
          s=subset(YearHT,YearHT$berthlet==i)
          unlist(c(strsplit(i,'\\|'),median(s$berthtime)))
       }
)
```

Both of those should run at about the same speed

(Note: both are untested, for lack of data, so they might be a little buggy)

Something else you can try that might have a smaller effect would be dropping the `subset` call and use indexing. The content of your `for` loop could be boiled down to

```
unlist(c(strsplit(i, '\\|'),
         median(YearHT[YearHT$berthlet == i, "berthtime"])))
```

But I'm not sure how much time that would save.